# Excel How to update a field based on a dropdown box relevant to another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula, excel-2013, vba

I essentially have a table formatted on sheet 1 in the following way (simplified but you should get gist)

```
COL A (SITE) | COL B (IP) | COL C (SUBNET) | COL D (GATEWAY
1
2
3
4
```

I then have a second sheet with a dropdown that will choose a value in COL A

And then several cells on this page that I want to update based on that drop down.

```
SITE DROPDOWN: [VALUE FROM COL A]

FIELD: [SHOULD SHOW VALUE FROM COL B RELEVANT TO DROPDOWN]

FIELD 2: [SHOULD SHOW VALUE FROM VOL C RELEVANT TO DROPDOWN]
```

Could anybody help with getting this set-up in Excel 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
Field = VLOOKUP(<Cell containing selected Site>, Sheet1!A:D, 2, FALSE)

Field 2 = VLOOKUP(<Cell containing selected Site>, Sheet1!A:D, 3, FALSE)
```